# cannot upload multiple image using vue.js in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I want to upload multiple images in  laravel, for that i'm using following code but i'm getting error :

> message: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on
> string

```
formData.append('gallery_img[]', this.form.gallery_img); 
uploadGalleryImg(e){
              
                var files = e.target.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;

                for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    this.form.gallery_img.push(files[i]);
                }
            },
```

> Controller :

```
 if (count(array($request->gallery_img))) {
        foreach ($request->gallery_img as $image) {
            $fileName = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path('img/gallery_img/'), $fileName);
        }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I'd guess your `this.form.gallery_img` doesn't contain a `File` instance. Could you add the output of `dd('$request->gallery_img)`?

Comment: @FabianBettag: when i console this.form.gallery_img.push it prints multiple files that i have uploaded

Comment: And those are instances of `File`? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Try with `foreach ($request->file('gallery_img') as $image)`

Comment: @FabianBettag: Added screenshot Please check

Answer (score 0):

Try making your foreach like this:

```
foreach ($request->gallery_img as $key => $image)
```

The thing is that $image is considered to be a string, so I think it's the key and its value is the actual image.
If that doesn't work, and you want just to get the extension from the filename, you can use the explode native php function with the "." delimeter.

```
$explodedImage = explode(".",$image);
$extension = $explodedImage[count($explodedImage)-1]
```

Comment: when i dd($request->gallery_img) i'm getting array:1 [
  0 => "[object File],[object File]"
]

Comment: now i'm getting this error : message: "Call to a member function move() on string",…}

Comment: Make sure you're providing enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form. And you can use my second solution to get the extension of the file.

Comment: what if you change that in the original code : $request->file('gallery_img') instead of $request->gallery_img

Comment: Did you get solution to this? I have the same problem